# Pandas - finding anomaly in paired column values in large Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been banging my head against a wall on this for a couple of hours, and would appreciate any help I could get.

I'm working with a large data set (over 270,000 rows), and am trying to find an anomaly within two columns that should have paired values.

From the snippet of output below - I'm looking at the Alcohol_Category_ID and Alcohol_Category_Name columns.  The ID column has a numeric string value that should pair up 1:1 with a string descriptor in the Name column. (e.g., "1031100.0" == "100 PROOF VODKA".

As you can see, both columns have the same count of non-null values. However, there are 72 unique IDs and only 71 unique Names.  I take this to mean that one Name is incorrectly associated with two different IDs.

```
        County  Alcohol_Category_ID  Alcohol_Category_Name   Vendor_Number  \
count   269843              270288                270288        270920   
unique      99                  72                    71           116   
top       Polk           1031080.0        VODKA 80 PROOF           260   
freq     49092               35366                 35366         46825   
first      NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
last       NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
mean       NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
std        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
min        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
25%        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
50%        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
75%        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN   
max        NaN                 NaN                   NaN           NaN
```

My trouble is in actually isolating out where this duplication is occurring so that I can hopefully replace the erroneous ID with its correct value.  I am having a dog of a time with this.

My dataframe is named i_a.

I've been trying to examine the pairings of values between these two columns with groupby and count statements like this:

```
i_a.groupby(["Alcohol_Category_Name", "Alcohol_Category_ID"]).Alcohol_Category_ID.count()
```

However, I'm not sure how to whittle it down from there. And there are too many pairings to make this easy to do visually.

Can someone recommend a way to isolate out the Alcohol_Category_Name associated with more than one Alcohol_Category_ID?

Thank you so much for your consideration!

EDIT: After considering the advice of Dmitry, I found the solution by continually pairing down duplicates until I honed in on the value of interest, like so:

```
#Finding all unique pairings of Category IDs and Names
subset = i_a.drop_duplicates(["Alcohol_Category_Name", "Alcohol_Category_ID"])

#Now, determine which of the category names appears more than once (thus paired with more than one ID)
subset[subset["Alcohol_Category_Name"].duplicated()]
```

Thank you so much for your help.  It seems really obvious in retrospect, but I could not figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Why not just make a subset of unique rows and quickly see where the discrepancy happens? `subset = i_a.drop_duplicates(["Alcohol_Category_Name", "Alcohol_Category_ID"])` which should return a data frame with 72 rows and you will quickly be able to see where the name is mapping to two different IDs.

Comment: Thanks so much - this helped immensely.  I figured there had to be an uncomplicated way of doing this.  It just never occurred to me to keep parsing out duplicates until I found what I was looking for.  You're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think this snippet meets your needs:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,3], 'b':[1,2,1,1,2,1]})
```

So `df.a` has 3 unique values mapping to 2 uniques in `df.b`.

```
> df.groupby('b')['a'].nunique()
b
1    2
2    1
```

That shows that df.b=1 maps to 2 uniques in a (and that df.b=2 maps to only 1).